# Implementing a scroll function on a playing map

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, scroll

I'm using the MVVM model to create a App. I've implemented Zoom and I can move a unit around when I select it. However I'm not sure how to implement scroll, so far I've implemented:

```
        ZoomStartedCommand = new RelayCommand<ManipulationStartedEventArgs>(ZoomStart);
        ZoomDeltaCommand = new RelayCommand<ManipulationDeltaEventArgs>(ZoomDelta);
        ZoomCompletedCommand = new RelayCommand<ManipulationCompletedEventArgs>(ZoomCompleted);

public void ZoomStart(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement Element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;

    }

    public void ZoomDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PinchManipulation != null)
        { 
             Map.deltaZoom = Map.deltaZoom * e.PinchManipulation.DeltaScale;
        }
        else
        {
            FrameworkElement Element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;

            Point P = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation;
            Map.TranslateX += P.X;
            Map.TranslateY += P.Y;
}

    }

    public void ZoomCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement Element = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;


    }
```

My View looks like:

```
<Grid x:Name="Map" Width="1271" Height="1381.5">


    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=Map.deltaZoom}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=Map.deltaZoom}"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Path=Map.TranslateX}" Y="{Binding Path=Map.TranslateY}"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationStarted">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ZoomStartedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationDelta">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ZoomDeltaCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="ManipulationCompleted">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=ZoomCompletedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Canvas/>

</Grid>
```

However when I implement it this way the Scroll lags, any way to avoid this lag?